# Clear "Recent Labels" list in Gmail

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, gmail

It's bugged me for awhile that Gmail shows a "Recent Labels" list when viewing the labels.  Does anyone know how to clear this list or even remove it?

Gmail: 4.7.1

OS: Jelly Bean - 4.1.2

Answer (score 5):

Although the **Original** **Answer** is already in place, let me just re-phrase it, which hopefully resemble Vanilla Android AOSP based phones.

1. Open "Settings" application
2. Choose "Apps" or "Applications" from the list of different Settings.
3. Locate "GMail" App in the List of Apps shown.
4. Select "Gmail" App and in this screen, there is "Clear Data" option available.  Tap the button Clear data. Confirm the operation and wait for Gmail Sync to complete.

This should clear the Recent labels.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Go to App info for Gmail: Open app drawer and drag up the Gmail icon to the option **App Info**.
2. Tap the button **Clear data**. Confirm the operation.
3. Wait for Gmail sync.

You'll be greeted again as if it was the first time you opened Gmail, but **Recent labels** list will be cleared.